# Unicode quotes automatically evaluates in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

I am currently wrestling with json strings that have unicode encoded quotes like so:

```
'{"test":"\u0022"}'
```

Which when cast as a string evaluates as so:

```
'{"test":"""}'
```

This causes a loads to break with a ValueError:

```
>>> json.loads('{"test":"\u0022"}')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/json/decoder.py", line 352, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/json/decoder.py", line 368, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 11 (char 10)
>>>
```

I am able to alleviate this by taking the input as a byte string before it gets interpreted by the utf-8 encoding and running a find/replace on that; however, this is impossible for the inputs I am dealing with in reality since they will be coming from a library query to an api which passes back a utf-8 encoded string.

Is there a way to keep python from auto encoding these unicode characters?

Comment: cannot reprodue: `In [6]: json.loads('{"test":"\u0022"}') Out[6]: {u'test': u'"'}`. can you post http://http://sscce.org ?

Comment: @m.wasowski: Are you on Python 2 or 3? On Python 2, strings are byte strings instead of unicode, so unicode escapes aren't interpreted.

Comment: I should add I am using python 3, I believe this isn't an issue in python 2.

Comment: yes, I figured it out and replaced on of tags, to indicate that it is python3 only problem. I is confirmed on Python 3.3

Comment: If your API gives you a UTF-8 encoded string, that *would be* a bytestring (which you would need to decode into a `str` before passing to `json.loads`). Note that Python is *decoding* the character rather than encoding it. Do you mean that your db api returns `str`?

Answer (score 3):

If you're getting your strings from an API query, they will already be appropriately escaped. When you write

```
'{"test":"\u0022"}'
```

in a source file, Python interprets the `\u0022` as meaning that a literal `"` should be included in the string there. When you get the string from properly-written API code, the string will contain a literal backslash, `u`, and digits. It'll be equivalent to the following written in a source file:

```
'{"test":"\\u0022"}'
```

If your code fails on actual data from the API query, either the API is broken (possible but unlikely), or you've done some sort of incorrect processing on it, perhaps double-parsing the escapes somehow.

Comment: I am pulling json from the tumblr api, which looks like this: http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/distant-traveller.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=IkJtqSbg6Nd3OBnUdaGl9YWE3ocupygJcnPebHRou8eFbd4RUv&id=79086448801

Comment: @user1268026: The data looks fine to me. You should be able to use it with no problems. You can't just copy-paste it into a source file between single quotes, or you'll have double-parsing problems, but reading it from a request response should just work.

Comment: Yeah, I was just being stupid with how I was using the request object and getting decoded results.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is, you have in your example byte strings. You can either request unicode, or decode them like in this example:

```
txt = b'{"test":"\u0022"}'
json.loads(txt.decode())
Out[10]: {'test': '"'}
```

It might be clearer for you if you see how unicode literal should look like:

```
txt.decode()
Out[12]: '{"test":"\\u0022"}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem appears to be that you are copying and pasting a string into Python without escaping the special characters. It is Python, not the json module, that turns `\u0022` into a quote - and that parsing only runs on string *literals*, or things passed to eval. If you retrieve the data problematically, you won't have this problem:

```
>>> import requests
>>> resp = requests.get("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/distant-traveller.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=IkJtqSbg6Nd3OBnUdaGl9YWE3ocupygJcnPebHRou8eFbd4RUv&id=79086448801")
>>> json.loads(resp.text)
# Gives data, not an error
```

If you do want to paste it into your source file, use raw strings, which disable Python's `\u...` parsing for that literal, so that you end up with *those literal characters* in the string rather than the single decoded one:

```
>>> json.loads(r'{"test":"\u0022"}')
{'test': '"'}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was passing in the request object into a library that was passing back the decoded bytestring, which I was trying to pass into loads. Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 0):

You *should* be getting a `bytes` object containing the json string. You'll need to decode it to `json.loads` it. Works fine for me with Python3

```
>>> url = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/distant-traveller.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=IkJtqSbg6Nd3OBnUdaGl9YWE3ocupygJcnPebHRou8eFbd4RUv&id=79086448801"
>>> import json, urllib.request
>>> jdata = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
>>> json.loads(jdata.decode())
{'meta': {'msg': 'OK', 'status': 200}, 'response': {'total_posts': 1, 'blog': {'is_nsfw': False, 'ask': True, 'ask_page_title': 'Ask me anything', 'posts': 5152, 'url': 'http://distant-traveller.tumblr.com/', 'name': 'distant-traveller', 'likes': 44022, 'description': '"The surface of the Earth is the shore of the cosmic ocean... Recently, we\'ve managed to wade a little way out, and the water seems inviting." - Carl Sagan', 'share_likes': True, 'updated': 1395784772, 'title': 'Voyage into Space', 'ask_anon': True}, 'posts': [{'source_url': 'http://wonderous-world.com/post/77780009786/starry-sky-and-jupiter-by-timo-braun', 'image_permalink': 'http://distant-traveller.tumblr.com/image/79086448801', 'link_url': 'http://wonderous-world.tumblr.com', 'source_title': 'wonderous-world', 'photos': [{'caption': '', 'alt_sizes': [{'height': 750, 'width': 500, 'url': 'http://31.media.tumblr.com/159388efacbfa78e281fd5aa0476864f/tumblr_n1jddlcPjW1r787hmo1_500.jpg'}, {'height': 600, 'width': 400, 'url': 'http://25.media.tumblr.com/159388efacbfa78e281fd5aa0476864f/tumblr_n1jddlcPjW1r787hmo1_400.jpg'}, {'height': 375, 'width': 250, 'url': 'http://31.media.tumblr.com/159388efacbfa78e281fd5aa0476864f/tumblr_n1jddlcPjW1r787hmo1_250.jpg'}, {'height': 150, 'width': 100, 'url': 'http://25.media.tumblr.com/159388efacbfa78e281fd5aa0476864f/tumblr_n1jddlcPjW1r787hmo1_100.jpg'}, {'height': 75, 'width': 75, 'url': 'http://24.media.tumblr.com/159388efacbfa78e281fd5aa0476864f/tumblr_n1jddlcPjW1r787hmo1_75sq.jpg'}], 'original_size': {'height': 750, 'width': 500, 'url': 'http://31.media.tumblr.com/159388efacbfa78e281fd5aa0476864f/tumblr_n1jddlcPjW1r787hmo1_500.jpg'}}], 'id': 79086448801, 'state': 'published', 'tags': [], 'date': '2014-03-09 20:01:37 GMT', 'timestamp': 1394395297, 'note_count': 7503, 'reblog_key': 'IFKcbmbd', 'short_url': 'http://tmblr.co/ZbkMUw19fwt2X', 'blog_name': 'distant-traveller', 'post_url': 'http://distant-traveller.tumblr.com/post/79086448801/wonderous-world-starry-sky-and-jupiter-by-timo', 'slug': 'wonderous-world-starry-sky-and-jupiter-by-timo', 'type': 'photo', 'caption': '<p><a class="tumblr_blog" href="http://wonderous-world.com/post/77780009786/starry-sky-and-jupiter-by-timo-braun">wonderous-world</a>:</p>\n<blockquote>\n<p><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/timobraunphotos/12695374254/">Starry Sky and Jupiter</a> by\xa0<a class="owner-name truncate" href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/timobraunphotos/" title="Go to Timo Braun\'s photostream" data-track="attributionNameClick">Timo Braun</a></p>\n</blockquote>', 'format': 'html', 'highlighted': []}]}}
```

pretty printed version:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(json.loads(jdata.decode()))
{'meta': {'msg': 'OK', 'status': 200},
 'response': {'blog': {'ask': True,
                       'ask_anon': True,
                       'ask_page_title': 'Ask me anything',
                       'description': '"The surface of the Earth is the shore of the cosmic ocean... Recently, we\'ve managed to wade a little way out, and the water seems inviting." - Carl Sagan',
                       'is_nsfw': False,
                       'likes': 44022,
                       'name': 'distant-traveller',
                       'posts': 5152,
                       'share_likes': True,
                       'title': 'Voyage into Space',
                       'updated': 1395784772,
                       'url': 'http://distant-traveller.tumblr.com/'},
              'posts': [{'blog_name': 'distant-traveller',
                         'caption': '<p><a class="tumblr_blog" href="http://wonderous-world.com/post/77780009786/starry-sky-and-jupiter-by-timo-braun">wonderous-world</a>:</p>\n<blockquote>\n<p><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/timobraunphotos/12695374254/">Starry Sky and Jupiter</a> by\xa0<a class="owner-name truncate" href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/timobraunphotos/" title="Go to Timo Braun\'s photostream" data-track="attributionNameClick">Timo Braun</a></p>\n</blockquote>',
                         'date': '2014-03-09 20:01:37 GMT',
                         'format': 'html',
                         'highlighted': [],
                         'id': 79086448801,
                         'image_permalink': 'http://distant-traveller.tumblr.com/image/79086448801',
                         'link_url': 'http://wonderous-world.tumblr.com',
                         'note_count': 7503,
                         'photos': [{'alt_sizes': [{'height': 750,
                                                    'url': 'http://31.media.tumblr.com/159388efacbfa78e281fd5aa0476864f/tumblr_n1jddlcPjW1r787hmo1_500.jpg',
                                                    'width': 500},
                                                   {'height': 600,
                                                    'url': 'http://25.media.tumblr.com/159388efacbfa78e281fd5aa0476864f/tumblr_n1jddlcPjW1r787hmo1_400.jpg',
                                                    'width': 400},
                                                   {'height': 375,
                                                    'url': 'http://31.media.tumblr.com/159388efacbfa78e281fd5aa0476864f/tumblr_n1jddlcPjW1r787hmo1_250.jpg',
                                                    'width': 250},
                                                   {'height': 150,
                                                    'url': 'http://25.media.tumblr.com/159388efacbfa78e281fd5aa0476864f/tumblr_n1jddlcPjW1r787hmo1_100.jpg',
                                                    'width': 100},
                                                   {'height': 75,
                                                    'url': 'http://24.media.tumblr.com/159388efacbfa78e281fd5aa0476864f/tumblr_n1jddlcPjW1r787hmo1_75sq.jpg',
                                                    'width': 75}],
                                     'caption': '',
                                     'original_size': {'height': 750,
                                                       'url': 'http://31.media.tumblr.com/159388efacbfa78e281fd5aa0476864f/tumblr_n1jddlcPjW1r787hmo1_500.jpg',
                                                       'width': 500}}],
                         'post_url': 'http://distant-traveller.tumblr.com/post/79086448801/wonderous-world-starry-sky-and-jupiter-by-timo',
                         'reblog_key': 'IFKcbmbd',
                         'short_url': 'http://tmblr.co/ZbkMUw19fwt2X',
                         'slug': 'wonderous-world-starry-sky-and-jupiter-by-timo',
                         'source_title': 'wonderous-world',
                         'source_url': 'http://wonderous-world.com/post/77780009786/starry-sky-and-jupiter-by-timo-braun',
                         'state': 'published',
                         'tags': [],
                         'timestamp': 1394395297,
                         'type': 'photo'}],
              'total_posts': 1}}
```